# Use JDOM to query an XML file? Like SQL but with XML?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm making a 2D game with LWJGL at the moment. I'm using JDOM as a base for storing information in XML files.

My items.xml file is structured as follows:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Item</name>
        <description>This is an item</description>
    </item>
</items>
```

There will be a lot of items in the file. So I want to be able to select a specific item, where the  tag matches the given id I want to search for. I understand how to get ALL the information from the file, but how can I get just a specific item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xpath - I use it at work when handling xml files in java. It's pretty nice. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/

Comment: Thanks, I had seen a couple things about that, but wasn't sure if it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you trully wish SQL for XML you should also check out [XQuery](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xjavaxquery/). It's another technology centered around XPath. I believe [SaxonB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/) provides an opensource implementation of it. It may be overkill to actually use it - depending on the complexity of your XML.